# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP в типе datetime

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Добавил в таблицу колонку типа datime со значением CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, чтобы при добавлении и изменении записей указывалось время последних изменений. После добавления новой записи все работает корректно, а после внесения изменений, дата не меняется. Как можно поправить?

Comment: Покажите точный запрос на добавление (или DDL после добавления). Есть подозрение. что DEFAULT указан, а вот ON UPDATE нет.

Comment: @Akina `public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }`

Comment: Ну вообще-то предполагалось, что мы увидим либо использованный ALTER TABLE, либо итоговый SHOW CREATE TABLE. А что там в PHP происходит, это никому неинтересно и не влияет.

Comment: Решил проблему, поставив в атрибут on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP